# How to stop page refresh after okta token refresh after every 2 min

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, okta, okta-api

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { useOktaAuth } from "@okta/okta-react";
import { Superadmin } from "../../../../Application_Constants";
import { AuthPage } from "./AuthPage";
import { ErrorPage1 } from "../../errors/ErrorPage1";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducer from "../../redux/reducer";
import Header from "../../header/Header";

const AppWithRouterAccess = () => {
  const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

  const theme = useTheme();
  const { authState, oktaAuth } = useOktaAuth();

  return (
    <Switch>
      {!authState.isAuthenticated ? (
        /*Render auth page when user at `/auth` and not authorized.*/

        <Route>
          <AuthPage />
        </Route>
      ) : (
        /*Otherwise redirect to root page (`/`)*/
        <Redirect from="/auth" to="/" />
      )}

      <Route path="/error" component={ErrorPage1} />

      {!authState.isAuthenticated ? (
        /*Redirect to `/auth` when user is not authorized*/
        <Redirect to="/auth/login" />
      ) : (
        <>
          {/* provider used to integrates redux store with react application */}
          {/* redux provides a centralized store to manage the state of application */}
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Header />
          </Provider>
        </>
      )}
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default AppWithRouterAccess;
```

This is AppWithRouterAccess.js file. `authState.isAuthenticated` is getting refresh because Okta token refreshes and my page is getting refreshed and store refreshes. How can I stop my Redux to get refreshed after `authState.isAuthenticated` updates. Redux store should not get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `store` is recreated each time `AppWithRouterAccess` renders for any reason. Create the `store` ***outside*** the component so it's instantiated only once.

```
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const AppWithRouterAccess = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const { authState, oktaAuth } = useOktaAuth();

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Switch>
        {!authState.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Route>
            <AuthPage />
          </Route>
        ) : <Redirect from="/auth" to="/" />
        }

        <Route path="/error" component={ErrorPage1} />

        {!authState.isAuthenticated
          ? <Redirect to="/auth/login" />
          : <Header />
        }
      </Switch>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Correct, though does that answer the question as to why the component renders multiple times?

Comment: @GregFenton OP isn't asking that question though. It was my understanding the component is rerendering, presumably from Okta invalidating a session or updating *something* in *its* code, and OP wants to know why the store is refreshed, e.g. reset. OP seems to understand the "why rerender" part well enough.

Comment: If application is open in 2 tab then page is getting refresh

Answer (score 0):

A React component renders for only one of 2 reasons:

- its parent renders (thus rendering all its children)
- a state variable in the component is given a new value via its "set state function"

Now, note that hooks (i.e. functions named `useXXX()`) and have state variables so if your component uses a hook that has state variables and those state variables in the hook update, then your component will re-render (because resources in Hooks are considered part of the component that calls the hook).

So, is it that the `useOktaAuth()` component has state variables that are updating frequently, thus causing the above component to re-render?